# Use Dynamic ORDER BY with DISTINCT in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @OrderBy VARCHAR(100)

SET @OrderBy='DealerCode ASC'

SELECT DISTINCT TOP (10)    
    d.Id, d.DealerCode,d.AffiliationCode,d.LegalName,d.ShipperCode,d.PrimaryUserId,d.PrimaryContactId,d.Zip,              
    d.Address1,d.Address2,d.IsActive,u.IsActive,d.City,d.[State],c.Name,u.UserName,d.RegistrationIntiatedDate,
    d.RegistrationCompletedDate,              
    rs.[Description],u.EntityId,dbo.fnGetCheckHours(d.Id)               
    FROM Dealer d              
    LEFT JOIN [User] u ON d.PrimaryUserId=u.Id              
    LEFT JOIN RegistrationSource rs ON d.RegistrationSourceId=rs.Id              
    LEFT JOIN Country c ON d.CountryId=c.id              
    LEFT JOIN ShippingNote sn ON d.Id=sn.DestinationId              
    LEFT JOIN Yard y ON sn.YardID=y.Code              
    LEFT JOIN Terminal t ON y.TerminalId=t.Id                
    WHERE t.Id='9a77168f-e5b6-4dd0-b26e-f95249c8e189' AND sn.destinationtype='Dealer'
    ORDER BY +'d.'+@OrderBy
```

But I am getting below error:

> Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

I am also using CASE but again I got above error

Comment: If you want to do it in that manner, you'll need to wrap the entire query in a string and execute that string

Answer (score 1):

Try using Dynamic query

```
DECLARE @OrderBy VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(8000)

SET @OrderBy='DealerCode ASC'

SET @SQL = 'SELECT DISTINCT TOP (10)    
    d.Id, d.DealerCode,d.AffiliationCode,d.LegalName,d.ShipperCode,d.PrimaryUserId,d.PrimaryContactId,d.Zip,              
    d.Address1,d.Address2,d.IsActive,u.IsActive,d.City,d.[State],c.Name,u.UserName,d.RegistrationIntiatedDate,
    d.RegistrationCompletedDate,              
    rs.[Description],u.EntityId,dbo.fnGetCheckHours(d.Id)               
    FROM Dealer d              
    LEFT JOIN [User] u ON d.PrimaryUserId=u.Id              
    LEFT JOIN RegistrationSource rs ON d.RegistrationSourceId=rs.Id              
    LEFT JOIN Country c ON d.CountryId=c.id              
    LEFT JOIN ShippingNote sn ON d.Id=sn.DestinationId              
    LEFT JOIN Yard y ON sn.YardID=y.Code              
    LEFT JOIN Terminal t ON y.TerminalId=t.Id                
    WHERE t.Id=''9a77168f-e5b6-4dd0-b26e-f95249c8e189'' AND sn.destinationtype=''Dealer''
    ORDER BY d.' + @OrderBy

    EXEC(@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the order as variable in a compiled query. You can try to build your query like this

```
DECLARE @OrderBy VARCHAR(100)

SET @OrderBy='DealerCode'

SELECT DISTINCT TOP (10)    
    d.Id, d.DealerCode,d.AffiliationCode,d.LegalName,d.ShipperCode,d.PrimaryUserId,d.PrimaryContactId,d.Zip,              
    d.Address1,d.Address2,d.IsActive,u.IsActive,d.City,d.[State],c.Name,u.UserName,d.RegistrationIntiatedDate,
    d.RegistrationCompletedDate,              
    rs.[Description],u.EntityId,dbo.fnGetCheckHours(d.Id)               
    FROM Dealer d              
    LEFT JOIN [User] u ON d.PrimaryUserId=u.Id              
    LEFT JOIN RegistrationSource rs ON d.RegistrationSourceId=rs.Id              
    LEFT JOIN Country c ON d.CountryId=c.id              
    LEFT JOIN ShippingNote sn ON d.Id=sn.DestinationId              
    LEFT JOIN Yard y ON sn.YardID=y.Code              
    LEFT JOIN Terminal t ON y.TerminalId=t.Id                
    WHERE t.Id='9a77168f-e5b6-4dd0-b26e-f95249c8e189' AND sn.destinationtype='Dealer'
    ORDER BY  CASE @OrderBy WHEN  'DealerCode' THEN d.DealerCode
                            WHEN  'AffiliationCode' THEN d.AffiliationCode
              END
```

Comment: I already use the CASES but I am getting the same problem as below   Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.